# Validating user credentials on Windows 10

Tags: c++, api, passwords, windows-10, credentials

Currently, I'm using the Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) to validate user credentials, as described in this article from Mircrosoft:
[How to validate user credentials on Microsoft operating systems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/180548/how-to-validate-user-credentials-on-microsoft-operating-systems)

This works generally well but I'm facing now an issue on a Windows 10 machine with the function [AcceptSecurityContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965462(v=vs.85).aspx) (used when generating the server context in the [SSPLogonUser](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/180548/how-to-validate-user-credentials-on-microsoft-operating-systems) method) returning error SEC_E_UNSUPPORTED_FUNCTION (0x80090302L).

Is there any alternative to validate user credentials on Windows 10 using Microsoft API?

Answer (score 0):

That error is generated because one of the parameters accepted by AcceptSecurityContext, `unsigned long  fContextReq`, was passed with the wrong value.

The values accepted are:

- ASC_REQ_ALLOCATE_MEMORY
- ASC_REQ_CONNECTION
- ASC_REQ_DELEGATE
- ASC_REQ_EXTENDED_ERROR
- ASC_REQ_REPLAY_DETECT
- ASC_REQ_SEQUENCE_DETECT
- ASC_REQ_STREAM

The documentation link that you provide in your question says that not all clients may support the parameter passed therein.

It then proceeds saying [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374770(v=vs.85).aspx) that not all flags are valid on a client and it suggests reading the post there carefully to understand what is available to you.

1. Make sure you are passing valid values to begin with
2. Check that the flag you are using can be used from a client and are not server-only